# OnLoadOptions cannot be hit in the AsyncPackage extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions

I want to get access to the VS2019 .suo file and I searched online and here is the suggested method.

Make your package class implements `IVsPersistSolutionOpts`.

```
public sealed class MyExtensionPackage : AsyncPackage, IVsPersistSolutionOpts
```

Add the following code to the package’s `InitializeAsync` method:

```
var solutionPersistenceService = GetService(typeof(IVsSolutionPersistence)) as IVsSolutionPersistence; solutionPersistenceService.LoadPackageUserOpts(this, "MyOption"); solutionPersistenceService.LoadPackageUserOpts(this, "MyOption2");
```

Add the `OnLoadOptions` method

```
protected override void OnLoadOptions(string key, Stream stream)
{
    if (key.Equals("MyOption", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))  
    {    
        _myOption = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();    
    }    
    else
    {
        base.OnLoadOptions(key, stream);
    }    
}
```

But when I run and load the extension, I cannot enter into the `OnLoadOptions()`, is there anything else I need to do to make it work?

Comment: Please refer to [this document](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.OnLoadOptions(string,%20System.IO.Stream)/).